# How can I sum a row of drop-down cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have a worksheet with several rows representing topics and columns with people's names. The cells each use the same data-validation drop-down to show how difficult each person thought each topic was.

I need to be able to add up the equivalent values for a row (e.g. as if the drop-down was numbered from the list-length for the first entry).

E.g.
Say the list is: Hard, Medium, Easy
A row is: Hard, Easy, Hard, Medium
The total is: 3+1+3+2 = 9

I'm pretty sure this is going to need google script coding so any help gratefully received!

I've tried `vlookup` and that just copies the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A8, 
 {"Easy",   1; 
  "Medium", 2; 
  "Hard",   3}, 2, 0))))
```

[image: 0]